# can the break statement terminate the while(true) loop ? or only the return statement can do it?

Tags: c++

bjarne stroustrup chapter 6 calculator.cpp. I have edited part of the program.
Ss it possible for the "at plus" to loop back to the "hey" without executing the break statement?

When I tried to calculate:

3
+
3
+
3
+
3
;

I am confused how did the "at plus" loop back to the "hey" at the case '+'. I added the "at plus" and "hey" to try to know the flow of the statement.

```
// deal with + and -
double expression()
{
    cout << "expression" << endl;
    double left = term();      // read and evaluate a Term
    cout << "welcome to expression()" << endl;
    Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream
    cout << "still at expression()" << endl;


    while (true) {
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '+':
            cout << "hey" << endl;
            left += term();    // evaluate Term and add
            t = ts.get();
            cout << "at plus" << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            left -= term();    // evaluate Term and subtract
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        default:
            ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
            return left;       // finally: no more + or -: return the answer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Put it in a loop?

Comment: so sorry. i am not very familiar with stackoverflow.

Comment: 1) `while (1) { ... }` or 2) `goto` (You can read that goto is absolute evil but it is not).

Comment: *i am confused how did the "at plus" loop back to the "hey" at the case '+'. * Did it? Why do you think so? Plz explain. Your question is very confusing/unclear.

Comment: @WorldTreeBoy *is it possible for the "at plus" to loop back to the "hey"* -- Questions that start out with "is it possible" has either a "yes" or "no" answer.  The answer is "yes".  The other aspect to asking questions like this is the following:  C++ is one of the most powerful computer languages out there.  It is used to design games, control machinery, creating operating systems, etc.  So if C++ was not able to perform a simple loop, wouldn't that be strange?

Comment: sorry. i just don't understand how it works. i am pretty confused right now.

Comment: Just follow the code, line by line. When a switch case finishes, it hits the break statement, the loop condition is evaluated, and we re-enter the switch. And while `goto` is not an *absolute* evil, it's not great and you should avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement can be somewhat confusing, because it can be used in a couple of different ways. Basically, it operates on the innermost thing that it could apply to. So those `break` statements that are **inside** the `switch` statement end the processing of the current `case`. That's all. A `break` statement outside the `switch` statement would end the loop:

```
void f() {
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> x;
        switch(x) {
            case 1:
                do_someting();
                break; // inside switch, so exits **this case**
            case 2:
                do_someting();
                break; // inside switch, so exits **this case**
        }
        break; // outside switch, inside while, so exits while
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You missing code so I made example,
remember it's usually bad practice, the code in case should be easy and readable.
all you need to do is wrap the code you want to be executed more then once inside for/while loop, keep in mind break outside of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j = 1;
    int k = 1;
    while(k > 0){
        switch(j){
        case 1:
            for (int  i =0; i <= 2; i ++){
               cout << "hey " << endl;
               cout << "bye " << endl;
            }
            k--;
            break;
        case 2:
            //execute this code
            break;
           }
   }
}
```

output: hey bye hey bye hey bye